# Como leer ficheros en json

Tags: php, json

He intentado buscar como arreglar esto en **Google** pero no encuentro el porqué el código está mal. Estoy intentando hacer que lea cada archivo `json` y que se vean todos los juegos del array.

El fallo que recibo es:

> **Fatal error:** Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in the "file name"

Este es el código:

```
<?php

$file = file_get_contents("a file in json");

$info = json_decode($lista);

$game = $info['game'];
$game_list = $game['file'];

foreach($game_list as $i){
  echo $i;
}

?>
{
  "Status": true,
  "Game": {
    "max": 60,
    "list":["league","bns","vindi"]
  },
  "Version": "1.8.8"
}


here is the json file:
{
  "Status": true,
  "Game": {
    "max": 60,
    "list":["league","bns","vindi"]
  },
  "Version": "1.8.8"
}
```

Comment: Para que convierta el JSON en array debes pasarle `true` aquí: `$info = json_decode($lista,TRUE);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error en pocas palabras dice:

> No puedes utilizar un objeto como un array

Cuando utilizas la instruccion `$info = json_decode($lista);`, estas convirtiendo el json en un objeto en `PHP`

Entonces, para utilizar las propiedades del objeto tienes que hacer algo como:

```
$game = $info->game;
$game_list = $game->file;
```

También la function `json_decode`, recibe otro parametro que es un booleano, y si le pasas `true`, ese json lo conviertes en un Array y ahora si ya lo podrías utilizar como lo tienes actualmente.

Te recomiendo que hagas depuración, para que conozcas el tipo de dato que tienes y sabrás como manipularlo usando:

```
var_dump($info);
```